# how do I lock my Apple ID?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I entered Apple ID to my iPhone 5 which "Find my iPhone" button was on and someone changed the password. Now every second I use the phone they ask me to sign in to iCloud.

How can I remove this ID and unlock my iPhone?

Comment: Which password. For the phone or iCloud ?. Pleas make your question a bit more understandable of what is going on. As it is it contradicts itself;  "every second I use the phone" "unlock my iPhone"

Comment: password of iCloud

Comment: the iCloud Id isnt for me and i dont know the password which has changed from someone. then iCloud locked my iphone and i need the new password

Answer (score 2):

The following official Apple article may be of help here: [Find My iPhone Activation Lock](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365)

In short, try to reset the password using the appropriate links inside that article.  In the event that someone highjacked your iCloud account you used to enable Find My iPhone with and you cannot reset the password, you need to contact Apple to get this feature unlocked.

Before you do, please have the proof of purchase available, because that is what they most-likely ask you to send in.  As sad as it sounds, but this procedure (calling Apple to unlock the device) typically takes about 2+ business days to complete.

Comment: the iCloud Id isnt for me and i dont know the password which has changed from someone. then iCloud locked my iphone and i need the new password

Comment: The first step, you want to do is to check for Activation Lock using the link in my answer.  If the status tells you, that the activation lock is on, you need to contact Apple as I wrote earlier.  If it is off, only your device thinks that it is locked.  To remove the lock in this case, you need to force restore the device following this article: (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263)  If you have a backup from before this happens, you can restore it from there, otherwise restoring the backup will put the device into the same situation as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your email try to recover the password via iforgot. Then you can disable the activation lock or enter the new password to use your device.

Answer (score 0):

Find my phone appication works with your country and location. Your password may not have been changed, it could sometimes be an operating system error. 
I have experienced such too.

What is your country and present location? 
You might have government policies which place restriction to certain applications. This could also determing the possibility of unlocking the phone and removing ID..